# GWT messages interface with lookup support

Tags: gwt, binding, message, deferred

I'm working on a new application and i need to make a messages interface with lookup, using the key to find the value (like ConstantsWithLookup, but capable to receive parameters). I have being investigating Dictionary class functionality but it lacks message customization through parameters.

With ConstantsWithLookup i can make the following:

```
myConstantsWithLookupInterface.getString("key");
```

and get something like:

```
Field must be filled with numbers
```

But i need to do this:

```
myMessagesWithLookupInterface.getString("key", "param1", "param2",...);
```

and get something like:

```
Field _param1_ must be filled with numbers greater than _param2_
```

I have no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GWT regular expressions](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/regexp/shared/RegExp.html):

```
//fields in your class
RegEx pattern1 = RegEx.compile("_param1_");
RegEx pattern2 = RegEx.compile("_param2_");

public String getString(String key, String replace1, String replace2){
    // your original getString() method
    String content = getString(key);
    content = pattern1.replace(content,replace1);
    content = pattern2.replace(content,replace2);
    return content;
}
```

If your data contains `Field _param1_ must be filled with numbers greater than _param2_` then this will replace `_param1_` with content of string `replace1`.

Comment: This requires the use of a ConstantsWithLookup, while I really need the extra capabilities of Messages (support for @PluralCount and SafeHtml as a return type).